# codeigniter base_url problems

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a site that can be accessed locally with a domain: http://example
and externally with an internet domain that can only work if you are not connected to my local network. The external site does not work well and it shows the following error:

```js
Access to font at 'http://localip/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
fa-solid-900.woff2:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
example.com/:1 Access to font at 'http://ip/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
fa-solid-900.woff:1 Fai

 - 

led to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://ip/assets/js/adminlte.min.js.map: 
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localip/assets/css/adminlte.css.map: 
example.com/:1 Access to font at 'http://localip/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
all.min.css:1 GET http://localip/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf net::ERR_FAILED
favicon.ico:1 GET http://example.com/favicon.ico 503
```

once I change the base_url to my external domain, it works fine externally but the local domain breaks. Please help if anyone know what is wrong.

Comment: So basically you want to connect your remote user with your localhost ?

Comment: Have you tried using relative URL's for loading the assets? Something like: `<link href="/assets/plugins/..../xxx.woof2"`. Then the browser should use the same hostname as the site is accessed on. You can also try and leave base_url empty so CI will figure it out itself.

Comment: Error you have mentioned is due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy. You should add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your header to allow resources to be downloaded from other origin.